# Is this 'paid or unpaid invoices' MySQL query possible?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to produce a query that will display 'paid' invoices. My query isn't working which means there's either an error in it or what I'm trying to achieve is impossible in this way.

```
// paid

$statement = "accounts_invoice i 
               INNER JOIN customer_type ct on i.invoice_customer_type = ct.customer_type_id 
               LEFT JOIN accounts_invoice_payment ip on i.invoice_id = ip.invoice_payment_invoice_id 
              WHERE invoice_posted='1' 
                AND (i.invoice_total_amount_exc_vat + i.invoice_total_vat_amount) = ip.TotalPayments" 
              . $where 
              . " ORDER BY invoice_id DESC";

$invoice_details_query = mysqli_query($con,
          "SELECT i.*, ct.customer_type_name, 
                  ip.invoice_payment_amount AS TotalPayments 
           FROM {$statement} 
           LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}") 
        or die(mysql_error());
```

The `$where` string is empty in this instance, you can delete it if you wish. You can also remove the 'LIMIT' as this is purely being used for pagination.

I'm simply trying to make a page to display paid or unpaid invoices and it's driving me mad considering it sounds so simple in theory!

Database structure;

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 08, 2015 at 05:17 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `propsyst_atlas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts_invoice`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts_invoice` (
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_customer_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_property_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_tenancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_branch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_terms` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `invoice_total_amount_exc_vat` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_total_vat_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_posted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `invoice_date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date_posted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_posted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=87 ;


-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 08, 2015 at 05:18 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `propsyst_atlas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts_invoice_payment`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts_invoice_payment` (
  `invoice_payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_method` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_invoice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `invoice_payment_date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_payment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=71 ;

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 08, 2015 at 05:58 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `propsyst_atlas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `customer_type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_type` (
  `customer_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_type_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: Are you getting any MySQL errors? It's hard to tell if your query is correct without knowing the Database design.

Comment: Please copy the DDL for the tables creation used in your query. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. No MySQL errors and I've just posted the table structures.

Comment: `FROM accounts_invoice i INNER JOIN customer_type ct `... where is the table called `customer_type`?

Comment: Floating point numbers are hard to compare, because db doesn't store them as exact values - [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html). I would use integers for amounts storing. Format to comma value at display.

Comment: Added customer_type table, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively your query is

```
SELECT
    i.*,
    ip.invoice_payment_amount AS TotalPayments
FROM accounts_invoice i 
LEFT JOIN accounts_invoice_payment ip
    ON i.invoice_id = ip.invoice_payment_invoice_id 
WHERE invoice_posted='1' 
AND (i.invoice_total_amount_exc_vat + i.invoice_total_vat_amount) = ip.TotalPayments
ORDER BY invoice_id DESC
```

and that query fails because the `ip.TotalPayments` in the where statement is an unknown column. You need to use the original name `ip.invoice_payment_amount`. The alias is only used in the returned set, not in the query itself.

Also, your database design could be improved. First I would advise to use `InnoDB` instead of `MyISAM`. That allows you to use foreign keys, so there's actually a relation between the tables.

Also I would move the `AND` part of the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause, like so:

```
SELECT
    i.*,
    ip.invoice_payment_amount AS TotalPayments
FROM accounts_invoice i 
LEFT JOIN accounts_invoice_payment ip
    ON i.invoice_id = ip.invoice_payment_invoice_id 
    AND (i.invoice_total_amount_exc_vat + i.invoice_total_vat_amount) = ip.invoice_payment_amount
WHERE invoice_posted='1' 
ORDER BY invoice_id DESC
```

The result of `SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id` contains every row of `A` and the matching rows of `B`. If `B` does not have a matching row for a row in `A`, the values for the columns in B are `NULL`. If you do not want that, but instead only want the rows of `A` that have a matching row in `B`, you should use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your query is working (no errors) but is displaying both paid and unpaid invoices.

Comment: Ignore the above, I never changed LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN!

Comment: Can you try: `SELECT i.*, ct.customer_type_name, 
                  ip.invoice_payment_amount AS TotalPayments 
           FROM testforstack.accounts_invoice i INNER JOIN testforstack.customer_type ct on i.invoice_customer_type = ct.customer_type_id 
               LEFT JOIN testforstack.accounts_invoice_payment ip on i.invoice_id = ip.invoice_payment_invoice_id 
              WHERE invoice_posted='1' 
                AND (i.invoice_total_amount_exc_vat + i.invoice_total_vat_amount) = ip.invoice_payment_amount ORDER BY invoice_id DESC;` replace `testforstack` with your database name.

Comment: @Arjan How would I change the query to show unpaid invoices?

Comment: I've tried changing it to AND (i.invoice_total_amount_exc_vat + i.invoice_total_vat_amount) = ip.invoice_payment_amount and making it a WHERE query but that returns no results.

Comment: @MichaelLB to get unpaid invoices, use a `LEFT JOIN` and add `AND invoice_payment_id IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That will work for invoices with no payments but not for invoices with a payment that isn't equal to the full invoice amount

Comment: There can be more than one payment against an invoice. E.g invoice total = £100, two payments of £50 could me made against the invoice

Comment: Makes sense, but the £100 invoice with two £50 payments won't show up as fully paid now. The query in the question did not express that need either. A query that correctly detects whether or not an invoice has been fully paid and that allows for partial payments, gets a lot more complex.

Comment: Ok, back to the drawing board. Do you think it'd be better posting a new question for help?

Comment: I would say it's worth a new question.