# MySQL query to display all paid and unpaid invoices where invoices can have multiple payments

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, please see their structure below. Basically, using MySQL/PHP, I need to construct two queries. One to display a list of paid invoices and the other to display unpaid invoices. An invoice can have more than one payment made against it. For example, a £100 invoice can be paid using any number of payments for varying amounts. An invoice can also have no payments made against it meaning the full balance is outstanding.

Can you help with the query?

I did have a go at the query myself (see [Is this 'paid or unpaid invoices' MySQL query possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895937/is-this-paid-or-unpaid-invoices-mysql-query-possible)) but I failed to mention that there can be more than one payment against an invoice.

Table structure;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts_invoice` (
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_customer_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_property_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_tenancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_branch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_terms` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `invoice_total_amount_exc_vat` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_total_vat_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_posted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `invoice_date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date_posted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_posted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=87 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts_invoice_payment` (
  `invoice_payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_method` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_invoice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `invoice_payment_date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_payment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=71 ;
```

Comment: `I did have a go at the query myself ` where is the query ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895937/is-this-paid-or-unpaid-invoices-mysql-query-possible

Comment: `invoice_payment_invoice_id` == `invoice_id` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What's your data and expected results?

Comment: **Michael** How can `invoice_payment_invoice_id == invoice_id` when they are both **AUTO_INCREMENT**

Comment: I think this is more likely **`invoice_payment_invoice_id = invoice_id`** Although you seem to be operating a naming convention for somewhere the other side of the _river sticks_

Comment: They are not both auto_increment?

Comment: Do you want me to upload some data?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you can really do this. In my experience, if I issue multiple invoices to clients and they make payments, it quickly becomes impossible to say which payment was against which invoice. Unless a specific Invoice is in dispute, the best you can do is compare payments made against the total amount due.

Comment: correct imo @Strawberry. It's really a question of Cash Application as you described. Any credit so to speak from oldest invoice gets rolled over to the next most aged, or it is an Account running balance solution

Comment: here is food for thought. Something like a ledger (general ledger). http://pakaccountants.com/running-balance-method-in-accounting/  Basically the invoices are debits, payments are credits. Gives a running balance. Dr means you owe (Debit Balance), Cr means you overpaid (Credit Balance). So you are merely missing a ledger table, and off course transactions and innodb

Comment: I agree with you both and my system does post to the ledgers in the background. E.g when a new invoice is raised a debit and credit entry is made and the same when an invoice is paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use PHP as little as possible. It is not a db engine. It will drag tremendously on even medium size data sets.

### Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
  invId int auto_increment primary key,
  custId int(11) not null,
  invAmt decimal(10,2) not null
);

CREATE TABLE payment
(
  pdId int auto_increment primary key,
  invId int not null,
  amt decimal(10,2) not null
);

-- NOTE you need foreign key (FK) constraints on your real table

insert invoice (custId,invAmt) values (101,9999);   -- 1
insert invoice (custId,invAmt) values (101,100);    -- 2
insert invoice (custId,invAmt) values (101,40);     -- 3
insert invoice (custId,invAmt) values (101,20);     -- 4
insert invoice (custId,invAmt) values (201,100);    -- 5

truncate table payment;
insert payment (invId,amt) values (1,10);   -- inv 1 pymt
insert payment (invId,amt) values (1,20);   -- inv 1 pymt
insert payment (invId,amt) values (1,30);   -- inv 1 pymt
insert payment (invId,amt) values (2,30);   -- inv 2 pymt
insert payment (invId,amt) values (2,70);   -- inv 2 pymt, now paid in full

insert payment (invId,amt) values (3,99);   -- inv 3 Overpayment
```

### All of them at once:

```
select i.invId,i.invAmt,ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as paid,i.invAmt-ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as due
from invoice i
left join payment p
on p.invId=i.invId
where i.custId=101
group by i.invId
order by i.invId
```

### Overdue:

```
select i.invId,i.invAmt,ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as paid,i.invAmt-ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as due
from invoice i
left join payment p
on p.invId=i.invId
where i.custId=101
group by i.invId
having due>0
order by i.invId
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
| invId | invAmt  | paid  | due     |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|     1 | 9999.00 | 60.00 | 9939.00 |
|     4 |   20.00 |  0.00 |   20.00 |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
```

### Paid in full:

```
select i.invId,i.invAmt,ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as paid,i.invAmt-ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as due
from invoice i
left join payment p
on p.invId=i.invId
where i.custId=101
group by i.invId
having due=0
order by i.invId
+-------+--------+--------+------+
| invId | invAmt | paid   | due  |
+-------+--------+--------+------+
|     2 | 100.00 | 100.00 | 0.00 |
+-------+--------+--------+------+
```

### Credit due:

```
select i.invId,i.invAmt,ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as paid,i.invAmt-ifnull(sum(p.amt),0) as due
from invoice i
left join payment p
on p.invId=i.invId
where i.custId=101
group by i.invId
having due<0
order by i.invId
```

Comment: the same query with due=0 will show those all paid up. Negative due amts are overpayments. good luck

Comment: Do you mean 'WHERE due=0'?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can't reference 'due' inside of the query

Comment: there you go. tested all 4. you probably need 1 or 2 of them

Comment: Very good work, thank you! Works perfectly and an extremely efficient solution!

Comment: don't forget FK and index fixes to all your tables, the former for sanity, the latter for speed. Your tables above show neither (except PK)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ? Have two queries.

```
<?php

try
{
    $s = $conn->query("SELECT * from accounts_invoice");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMEssage();
}

try
{
    $p = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from accounts_invoice_payment where invoice_payment_invoice_id = :id");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMEssage();
}
while($main_invoies = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $invc_sum=0;
    $invoiceid = $main_invoies->invoice_id;
    $totalAmount = ($main_invoies->invoice_total_amount_exc_vat) + ($main_invoies->invoice_total_vat_amount);
    $p->bindParam(':id', $invoiceid);
    while($sub_invoices = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $invc_sum = $invc_sum + ($sub_invoices->invoice_payment_amount);
    }
    if($invc_sum == $totalAmount)
    {
        echo "Invoice Paid";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invoice unpaid";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your query still returns all invoices then processes them using an if statement. I want the query to only return all paid or all unpaid invoices.

Comment: Could you please upload some test data?

Comment: Your solution does work but it's not as efficient as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelLB 
Glad that you found a solution :)

Comment: it does work akshay, just not as fast. never do in php what mysql can do tremendously faster. imagine 10k rows coming back, versus sql handing you the answer. PHP is a wonderful thing ... a high performance db engine it is not

Comment: @Drew
I got your point :) I'm actually playing with your queries right now to understand it further.

Comment: what @strawberry said under general comments is correct (having written a lot of acctg sw). The best solution is an Account running balance. Debits and Credits so to speak.